# ESPNOW messages being dropped

Tags: esp32

I have 13 ESP32-C3 devices in a room sending messages at a rate of up to 10 messages per device per second. All the devices are within wifi range of each other, and all the messages are sent as single-packet ESP-NOW transmissions. Each message is sent on the same wifi channel, and all messages are broadcast to everyone. There are no other wifi devices in the vicinity.

It seems, though I have not confirmed, that a significant fraction of ESPNOW messages are being dropped (20%?). How likely is it that I would see significant packet drop on the ESPNOW protocol at ~130 messages per second?

Is it more likely to be a transmission queuing problem on the sending side, or a receive queuing problem on the receiving side, or interference between simultaneous transmissions?

(I am coding in C using ESP-IDF 5.1. I am working with the ESP32-C3-DevKit2 board.)

Comment: Why broadcasting, does it really need broadcast? A ESP-NOW packet round trip take about 500uS in good reception and could go up to 2000uS-20000uS if signal is marginal. You can do some diagnostic yourself with your network. 1) add `unsigned long startTime = micro();` before calling `esp_now_send()`, and in your sendCallBack(), calculate the time taken with `micro() - startTime` to see how long each packet take to get ack. 2) the `sendCallBack(sendCallBack(uint8_t* mac, uint8_t sendStatus)` function returns a status that you can check whether the packet has been sent successfully or not.